# Need recursive BASH script to traverse folders and use wildcards

Tags: bash, recursion, command-line

We have been capturing and sending files to a REST server and saving them to PNG extensions from a toolbar, now have nearly a half a million files.

Recently we found they have been actually saving as base64 streamed files and not PNG format.

I have a python script that can convert them but is not recursive and connot use wildcards.

ImageMagick says the base64 files are too big(5K max) so thats out for the conversion.

```
 IE;  /bin/base64-to-png.py <base64_file_name>.png <output_name.png>
```

The directory paths /mnt/s3/pages/ where "pages" has several thousand numbered folders.

```
 IE; /mnt/s3/pages/100 

   "pages" subfolders are never more than 1 folder deep.
   The files are typically 5540_thumb.png, 5540_snapshot.png and 5540_crop.png 
   where the 5540 is the capture number.
```

I need a BASH script wrapper to make it recusive accross the folders, copy all originals to backup files (filename.b64) and pass wildcards as proper path/names to the python script, convert the files and leave the output file in the same respective folder then use mogrify to compress them.

```
 IE;  base64-to-png.sh *_snapshot.b64 *_snapshot.png <compression number>

  should

    cp <file_name.png> <file_name>.b64
    /bin/base64-to-png.py <file_name.png> <file_name.png>
    mogrify -quality <compression number> -format png <file_name.png>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script

```
#!/bin/bash
SEARCHPATH=$1
COMNUM=$2
FINDEXT="*.png"

for f in `find $SEARCHPATH -type f -name $FINDEXT` ; do
     #just get files name without extension
     fname=`echo $f | cut -d'.' -f1` 
     #perform operations
     cp $f ${fname}.b64
     /bin/base64-to-png.py $f $f
     mogrify -quality $COMNUM -format png $f

done
```

you can call it as

```
$ base64-to-png.sh /somepath/tofind 100

param 1 : path where to find `.png` files 
param 2 : compression number.
```

This assumes that `/bin/base64-to-png.py` can work on absolute path e.g. `/somepath/somedir/somefile.png` not just `somefile.png`

Warning: no QA done, use it on your risk!

Comment: I believe that in the for line the `$FINDEXT` should be double quoted, right?

Comment: Rohan your script worked fine all I needed was to change FINDEXT="*.png" to a command line variable only because thumb files needed to be compressed to a different ratio -- Many Thanks, this helped fantastically.

Comment: @user1213320 Nice to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Change filenames from png to base64:

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob

for file in *.png **/*.png; do
    if (file "${file}" | fgrep "ASCII" >/dev/null 2>&1); then
        # File is named '.png' but is ASCII, move it.
        b64name="${file%.*}.b64"
        mv -f "${file}" "${b64name}"

        # Insert command that converts $b64name to $file

        # I think this will work
        base64 -d "${b64file}" > "${file}" || echo "Conversion failed for ${b64file}"
        mogrify -quality  -format png "${file}"
    fi
done
```

Due to things like `globstar`, I believe this will require bash 4.0+.  You can find your version with `bash --version`

If it's vital that you use python for the base64 conversion, feel free to swap the command out.